# How can I scrape data inside this iframe by python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am going to get data of this link by python
https://www.jobbnorge.no/en/available-jobs/job/148574/project-manager-researcher-translational-nk-cell-biology

However, I can not get data due to it is inside a frame of google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about any frames of google or whatever you mean by that. The page you scrape is an Angular app, it renders data on the site due to the javascript running in your browser. I recommend you this package [requests-html](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) created by the author of very popular [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests).

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.jobbnorge.no/en/available-jobs/job/148574/project-manager-researcher-translational-nk-cell-biology')
r.html.render()
```

Now you can find the data you need, e.g. the heading:

```
>>> r.html.find('.heading-container > h1', first=True).text
'Project manager (researcher) - Translational NK cell biology'
```